# finding the unspecified ${\bf E}[X]$ and $\rm var(X)$ given the expectation of higher powers of $X$

Tags: probability, expectation, correlation

**Homework Problem:**

It is known that a for a standard normal random variable $X$, we have ${\bf E}[X^3]=0$, ${\bf E}[X^4]=3$, ${\bf E}[X^5]=0$, ${\bf E}[X^6]=15$. Find the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $X^3$.

**Answer:**

Since ${\bf E}[X]={\bf E}[X^3]=0$, we have ${\rm cov}(X,X^3)={\bf E}[X\cdot X^3]={\bf E}[X^4]=3$. Furthermore, since ${\rm var}(X)=1$ and ${\rm var}(X^3)={\bf E}[X^6]=15$, we obtain
$\rho (X,X^3)=\frac{3}{\sqrt {1}\cdot \sqrt {15}} =\sqrt {3/5}.$

Interestingly, even though the random variables are strongly dependent (the value of one determines the value of the other), the value of the correlation coefficient is moderate.

---

My approach was to try to solve for ${\bf E}[X]$ by calculating the covariance between various powers of $X$, but I couldn't come up with a way to isolate either ${\bf E}[X]$ or ${\rm var}(X)$.

The answer doesn't explain this. How is it determined that ${\bf E}[X]={\bf E}[X^3]=0$ and that ${\rm var}(X)=1$?

Comment: A standard normal random variable has mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: The standard normal is symmetric about $0$, so if $E(X^k)$ exists, where $k$ is odd, we must have $E(X^k)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it being a standard normal implies that $EX=0$ and $VX=1$.  But even without that knowledge you could have figured it out since

$$0=EX^3= E(X-\mu)^3 + 3 \mu E(X-\mu)^2 + 3 \mu^2 E(X-\mu) + \mu^3
= 3\mu\sigma^2 + \mu^3,$$

such that $\mu=0$ or $\mu^2=3\sigma^2$.

Further,

$$3=EX^4= E(X-\mu)^4 + 4 \mu E(X-\mu)^3 + 6 \mu^2 E(X-\mu)^2 + 4 \mu^3 E(X-\mu)+\mu^4 \\
= 3\sigma^4 + 6 \mu^2 \sigma^2 + \mu^4,$$

etcetera.